# How to fix " java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist "

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit-jupiter

This is my first springboot crud. Please help me to fix the errors .

```
package com.example1.fullstack_practice;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class FullstackPracticeApplicationTests {

    @Test
     void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add code and error messages as text not as image

Comment: Your image shows an error

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and then EDIT it to replace the screenshot with your actual code and error messages as text.  As written, the image makes your question subject to closure as "Unclear".

Comment: please add an error to the question description. And if it's your first spring boot application, then go to spring boot tutorial, it takes 15 minutes and it will resolve your issue: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: as a hint, I will tell, you are missing the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency from this tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the dependency to your class path. If you are using maven add:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

Comment: I have the same problem.
I have spring-boot-starter-test, which includes 5.9.3.
I verified that the External Libraries are in my intellij project.

I also tried explicitly adding jupiter dependency as mentioned above but still getting:  java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist.

I "Invalidate Cache and Restart" several times.
I "Reimport All Maven Projects" several times.
I "Rebuiid Project" several times.

I am runing temurin-17 and checked project structure multiple times.

Project will run, but I cannot run tests for reason above.

Comment: Given the OP is using Spring Boot, it shouldn't include a version, but let the version management of Spring Boot handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when changing the project's structure. I accidentally marked the 'src' directory as the Source Root, which caused the test dependencies 'spring-boot-starter-test' not to be pulled in.

Therefore, I recommend checking the project's structure. It's possible that your error is related to this.